# Predicting with Tensorflow gives different result each time

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, linear-regression

I am having doubts about my ANN built for multinominal linear regression in Tensorflow. I dont understand why each time I run the model I receive different predictions on a new data set, hence different prediction error. If I am correct, I am using for each model estimation the same training and testing set. Does it have anything to do with some files Tensorflow saves and then uses it over and over again?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn import cross_validation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

#Upload dataset into x0 and y0 / missing
x0 = np.array(X0) #convert into numpy array for ANN modelling
y0 = np.array(datap.power_consumption) # define the target variable (dependent variable) as y


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x0, y0, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

total_len = X_train.shape[0]

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 500
batch_size = 1
display_step = 1
dropout_rate = 0.9
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 32 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 200 # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 200
n_hidden_4 = 256
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
n_classes = 1

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 22])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None])

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch-1):
            batch_x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        # sample prediction
        label_value = batch_y
        estimate = p
        err = label_value-estimate
        print ("num batch:", total_batch)

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print ("[*]----------------------------")
            for i in range(1):
                print ("label value:", label_value[i], \
                    "estimated value:", estimate[i])
            print ("[*]============================")

    print ("Optimization Finished!")
    # Test model
    predicted_vals = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: X_test})
    rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_test, predicted_vals))
```

Thank you very much for explanation,
Regards!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can understand the details of your problem (this is one that is particularly sensitive to details).

Comment: Do you mean why you get different results each time you run the script, including training? That is just because of random weight initialization.

Comment: Yes, so does it mean that I should train the model several times, and once I get the lowest prediction error, save it for the future usage?

Comment: program run on same data over and over again ?in question you mentioned "*why each time I run the model I receive different predictions on a **new data set**, hence different prediction error*"